# Did the Patriarchs worship in a temple?

Tags: avot-patriarch-fathers

Would Abraham have gone somewhere specific to worship? Or any of the pre-Moses figures? Noah?

If so, what would that structure have looked like? Were there decorations? Sacred objects?

Also related, maybe: in Exodus, if the people were worshiping a golden calf, that would mean that the idea of sacred objects/places was universally familiar, right?

Comment: The partiarchs were building altars, as we read today for example. http://mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt0126.htm#25

Comment: The idea of prayer is connected to Isaac who was standing in a field.

Comment: No, they went thru three stages: Abraham call it הר - mountain, Itzhok called it שדה - field, and only Yaakov realized (only called) it "בית ה'"- Hashem's house. Those are different measures of closeness to Hashem. Anyway, in my understanding, the Temple is a tool for atonement for the Jewish people and that was not necessary before there was the Jewish nation and atonement for the sin of the Golden Calf and premature Exile.